# How can i throw exception using javascript from IN sequence in wso2

Tags: javascript, wso2

i'm validating a header field in the IN sequence , if its empty i need to throw a exception back to the client. How can i achieve this. Is there a throw function from the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate more on the requirement, after you validate it, you might simple use a fault mediator https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Fault+Mediator and respond back to client.